# Examples of compiling win32 api c programs (through command line) on windows

Tags: c, windows, compilation, tcc

Attempting to do something very simple - compile basic win 32 c programs through  windows cmd. This is something I should be able to do myself, but I am just so stuck here..

I keep stumbling into weird problems, vague errors. I dunno whether I should go into details. 
Using tcc ( tiny c compiler)

1. One simple hellowin.c example from a book required winmm.lib. How do I import it ? can someone give me the exact command for gcc/tcc /any command line compiler for windows(except cygwin) ? I did try various options after reading help , but it kept giving me a can't find stupid error.
2. a sample from platform sdk that I tried to compile gave a - winnt.h "( expected" error. this after a #define _M_IX86 . what it means ?
3. any general guide for compiling c programs for windows(win32 api) through command line ? . explaining what all should be #defined ..etc..

I have googled a lot but most of the c compiling guidelines for win32 programs focus on vb  .I wanna do it manually , on the command line.

Thanks

Comment: Can you include the actual errors you are getting?

Comment: Why not Cygwin? Would Mingw do instead?

Comment: @Jonathan: TCC is a standalone C compiler that is *extremely* lightweight compared to what you need to install for either of Cygwin or MinGW. http://bellard.org/tcc/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling C-code from the Command Prompt in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334219/compiling-c-code-from-the-command-prompt-in-windows)

Answer (score 1):

If I create a new project using Visual Studio it #defines the following preprocessor symbols using compiler command-line options:

- `WIN32`
- `_WINDOWS`
- one of either `_DEBUG` or `NDEBUG`
- `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` (although the Windows headers and libraries also support non-Unicode-enabled applications, if your compiler doesn't support Unicode).

http://bellard.org/tcc/tcc-doc.html says "For usage on Windows, see also tcc-win32.txt".

Answer (score 1):

Download the Windows PlatformSDK and it comes with its own command line compiler. It creates a shortcut Start->Programs->... to open a command prompt for either 32bit or 64bit. Select the 32bit variant and you get a fully initialized command prompt with compiler in your PATH and all INCLUDE, LIB and LIBPATH set.

cmd> cl hello.c

This should give you hello.exe. For more help on compiler "cl /?", for linker "link /?"

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the kind of compiler that might be looking for INCLUDE and LIB paths in the environment.  If you do "set" on the command line and don't see those vars listed, you could try setting them to the paths your compiler is using.  Not sure where you would have installed this tcc tool, but look for directories named 'include' and 'lib' and try assigning those to the aforementioned environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can try gcc from [equation.com](http://www.equation.com/). It's a mingw wrapped compiler, but you don't have to worry about mingw: just download, install and use. There's no IDE either.

The download page is at http://www.equation.com/servlet/equation.cmd?fa=fortran.