# C++ console program closing before completion.

Tags: c++, windows, console

My Program is a simple sum finder. the code of which I will post at the end. 
But it asks for the first number. Upon entering it asks you for a second number.
After entering the second number, the console window closes before showing the results. When I first build and tested in Visual C++ 2010 it ran fine, but this problem only occurs when running the .exe from the build location. Any tips?

Here is the code If testing yourself please re-assemble:

```
#include "stdafx.h" // for Visual Studio users
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  using namespace std;   
  int no1, no2, sum ;

  cout << "\nEnter the first number = " ;
  cin >> no1 ;

  cout << "\nEnter the Second number = " ;
  cin >> no2 ;

  sum = no1 + no2 ;

  cout << "\nThe sum of "<< no1 <<" and "<< no2 <<" = "<< sum  ; 

  return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Open a console window, run the program from there by typing a command line. The console window will stay open after the program has quit. This is how console programs are designed to be run.

Comment: As john says. The result is being displayed. But that is the end of the program so the window closes before you can see it. You can sleep the end of the program for a bit and i bet you catch the window with the sum.

Answer (score 3):

That's because the window closes when the program is finished running. Use `std::cin.get()` to keep the window open while it waits for input:

```
int main()
{
    // ...
    std::cin.get(); // keep the window open; wait for a character
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. I was able to use cin.clear();
cin.ignore(255, '\n');
cin.get()

Answer (score 2):

One way to keep the console open until you're satisfied with it is to add a cin at the end of it - Before closing it will then wait for the user to close it or to enter a line of input.

Comment: Ty for your answer I was able to use cin.clear();
cin.ignore(255, '\n');
cin.get();

Answer (score 2):

Console applications are actually meant to be executed directly from the console. If you run them directly on it, after the program is done you'll be left with your console window, containing all of the output given by your program. *Plus*, you'll get a little more used to using the command prompt, which is pretty cool and useful sometimes. :-D

If you have any doubts about how to run a program from the console on a windows environment, take a look at [this answer (Compiling C-code from the Command Prompt in Windows?)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1334232/1670308) or maybe [this one (How to run a c program using command prompt)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16367611/1670308).

Answer (score 2):

Add cin.get() before return 0;