# . / command results in an error: "syntaxe error un expected token"

Tags: c, github, cs50

I have a problem with my terminal I still a beginner and I am learning C programming using Cs50 code space my problem is : when I put this command
`. / file name`  this appears:

`line3: syntaxe error un expected token '('`

My code is:

```
#include <studio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
int main (void) 
{
printf ("hello world\n") ;
}
```

The code is so simple and nothing happened.

Comment: You have to compile your code before you can run it.  Put it in a file named `hello.c`, then type `cc hello.c`, and if that works, then type `./a.out`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a c program using command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367190/how-to-run-a-c-program-using-command-prompt)

Comment: "I am learning C programming using Cs50 code space" Okay, and in the CS50 course material, **what did they tell you to do** after writing the code?

Comment: I fear the stated error here has two misspellings in it, which perhaps indicates that it has not been copy+pasted from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

C source code is not directly executable. It must first be compiled to native code. For something as simple as the shown source, put your source code in a text file ending in the extension `.c`, then compile with:

```
cc filename.c
```

The default name for the output executable is `a.out`. You can execute this with:

```
./a.out
```