# Launching cl.exe from within program only works in certain circumstances

Tags: c++, windows, qt, system-calls, cl

So I have a Qt program ("Main") which (in its Windows incarnation) internally launches cl (the VS compiler).  I can launch the Main in one of three ways, and in two of these ways, the internal call to cl succeeds and the third, probably most important one, it fails with an 'cl is unrecognized program ...' error.  cl is called with `system`, and prior to calling it I follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334219/compiling-c-code-from-the-command-prompt-in-windows/1334232?noredirect=1#comment36731824_1334232) and run `vcvars32.bat`, also with `system`.

1. Main is launched from within QtCreator.  cl launches successfully in this case.
2. Main is launched from the Windows command line.  cl launches successfully in this case.
3. Main is launched by clicking on it within Explorer.  *cl fails to launch in this case*, again with the 'unrecognized program' error flashed briefly in the console.

I guess there is some environment which is either inherited from QtCreator (1) or set up when the Windows command line launches (2), but not when you click on an icon.  Just a guess though.  Anybody know what I can do to make things work in the case of (3)?  And using another compiler adds different complications so I'd just like to make this work with `cl` (to head off one obvious reply to this).  Also, I tried doing it using a `QProcess` but I had the same problem in all of 1-3.

Edit: Here is the call to vcvars32.bat

```
    int setup_code = system(setup.c_str());
   //Where setup is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"
```

This returns 0 (success) in all of 1-3.  The call to cl is then e.g.

```
   int code = system(cmd.c_str());
   //Where cmd is "cl /O2 "test.cpp" /Fe"test.exe""
```

This returns 0 for 1-2 and 1 in condition 3, i.e. ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION.

Comment: That's all very vague :-/ ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ok, I will add the exact system calls, maybe that will make it a little more concrete.  Otherwise, it's really as simple as what I've written, `cl` launches in two cases but not the third.

Comment: Have you tried a batch file that sets up the environment and runs the command you need all in one step.  Running vcvars in system is fine, but as soon as that call returns all of the environment you set up is gone, just like an out of scope variable.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Ok I will try this--at least the quick and dirty version whereby they're just concatenated in `system`.  Sounds very promising though.  I guess I had just assumed that there was a single 'virtual command line' or something that was maintaining the environment.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Concatenating as per [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/62850/execute-multiple-commands-with-1-line-in-windows-commandline) didn't work.  I guess I will look into creating an actual batch file.

Comment: If you're using Qt, why are you using `system()` and not `QProcess::start()` or `QProcess::startDetatched()`?

Comment: @RobbieE I did, but that didn't work either.  I guess I can take that approach a little further, connect some signals and look at the error messages.  But `system` should work.