# How do I run a C program from my Windows command prompt?

Tags: c, windows

Using Vim as an editor, I wrote the following simple code in C and saved it as helloworld.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
}
```

In command prompt, I wrote:

```
start chrome helloworld.c
```

This caused my browser to open up the file, but it did not print Hello World.  Instead, it just displayed the code I had written.  Did I not save it as a C file?

Also, I was wondering how to display the result of my C program inline on command prompt, as I am fairly new to it.  While searching the internet, I could not find any answers.  Am I supposed to do so from Vim?  I learned that you are supposed to do ./ in the gedit command box to display the result inline, but this does not work for the one that comes with Windows.

Please help and thank you for taking the time to read and answer.

Comment: You have to compile it to create an EXE file, using a C compiler like visual C++ or GCC. You can't do anything with it otherwise.

Comment: You are way, way off on getting started with C. First forget about Chrome and just try to compile and run from the command line. Better yet, find a basic tutorial and follow it. Also,  what are you trying to achieve? I'll guess that you should be learning JS instead of C.

Comment: See this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334219/compiling-c-code-from-the-command-prompt-in-windows

Comment: At revision 3, the question is completely different from the original question. This would confuse readers, as the comments and answers posted so far have nothing to do with the revised question. You should have posted a new question.

Comment: Definitely not right to completely change the question.  @TomZych, I rolled it back.

Comment: One you've posted a question **do not** change it into something completely different later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Ernest Friedman-Hill has already said, you normally have to compile the program. However, there are alternatives.

One alternative is the Tiny C Compiler, from http://bellard.org/tcc/. TCC does allow you to run the program without compiling it.

```
tcc -run helloworld.c
```

Does exactly what you want.

The Tiny C Compiler is not the only way to run C code from source without compiling it first. There are a few other alternatives.

- CSL: http://csl.sourceforge.net/csl.html
- Ch: https://www.softintegration.com/
- PicoC: https://code.google.com/p/picoc/
- CINT: http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint

I hope this helps.